# serviceSubscriberCellularProviders was deprecated in iOS 16.0

Tags: ios, swift, core-telephony, ios17

In our app, we are retrieving the SIM card country code.

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders
```

But 'serviceSubscriberCellularProviders' was deprecated in iOS 16.0 with no replacement.

So in iOS 17, is there any other way to get a SIM card-based country code or SIM card details?

Comment: You said it yourself; there is no replacement. This information is not available.  Some discussion here - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714876